# Require http:// or https:// in beginning of regular expression

Tags: regex

My regular expression works great except I want to add the requirement that the url must contain `http://` or `https://` and my attempts to fix the regular expression breaks it. Any help is appreciated!

```
    let rx = new RegExp(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/g);
let replaced = text.replace(
        rx,
        `<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>`
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?` with `https?:\/\/`. And since you are not using any variables to build the regex, use a regex literal and not the constructor notation.

```
/\bhttps?:\/\/(?:(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:\/[+~%\/.\w_-]*\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?[.!\/\\\w]*)?/g
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tMmV0v/1)

The `\bhttps?:\/\/`, matching `https://` or `http://` as a whole word, will apply to both the alternatives in `(?:(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)`, `(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+` and `(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+`, thus requiring the protocol before `www.`, too.

There are also many redundant capturing groups, consider removing those not needed and converting to non-capturing ones those you need to quantify.

```js
let text = "https://example.com http://example.com/more?k=v ftp://not.this.one www.example www.example.com";
let rx = /\bhttps?:\/\/(?:(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:\/[+~%\/.\w_-]*\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?[.!\/\\\w]*)?/g;
let replaced = text.replace(rx,'<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>'); 
console.log(replaced);
```

The `$&` backreference refers to the whole regex match value, no need to wrap the whole pattern with an additional pair of capturing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, it still matches www with no http or https, is there a way to require one of those and to not take www without it?